# libuv - How to use binary protocol

Tags: c, protocols, binary-data, libuv

I have client-server application when communicotion by simple  binary protocol. The binary protocol have 12 byte header (see code) when four byte is length of data [datasize] and data block size of datasize.

```
struct header {
    int32_t message_type;
    int32_t message_id;
    int32_t data_size;
};
```

dataflow:

---

header   |   data   |
   header   |   data   |

---

How to receive binary data from client by libuv? Do You know examples of processing binary data protocol by libuv?

Answer (score 2):

`libuv` uses the asyn events to notify new data arrived after you call `uv_read_start`. So you can get the binary data chunks from client in the callback function, something like `void data_callback(uv_stream_t *, size_t, uv_buf_t)`.

All you need to do next is composing the binary data chunks to the high layer protocol. You can setup a state machine for each client, feed it with data chunks and then emit the package to higher layer when a protocol package has completed.

I have a protocol parsing example similar with yours. It is a tcp client based on `libuv`. The protocol parsing module is here: [package.h](https://github.com/NetEase/libpomelo/blob/master/include/pomelo-protocol/package.h) and [package.c](https://github.com/NetEase/libpomelo/blob/master/src/package.c). Hoping it is helpful for you. :)